# fputcsv - columns from table displayed in one column

Tags: php, mysql, fputcsv

I have a problem with putting data from mysql database to csv file. The column headers are ok but rest of rows from table are in one column. Please help..

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","asasdd","asasdasd","asdasd");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
  $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

  $array = array("Id;Imie_i_nazwisko;Nazwa_kursu;Data_kursu");
  $array = str_replace('"', '', $array);
  fputcsv($output, $array);

  $rows = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM kursanci');
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
  {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Resolved should be like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","asd","asd","asd");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

  $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
  $array = array('Id','Imie_i_nazwisko','Nazwa_kursu','Data_kursu');
  fputcsv($output, $array, ';');

  $rows = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM kursanci');
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
  {
    fputcsv($output, $row, ';');
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: `$array = array("Id;Imie_i_nazwisko;Nazwa_kursu;Data_kursu")` The array contains a single string value..... what's with the `;` ? Are you trying to set `;` as the separator.... use fputcsv() properly

Comment: What's up with this nonsense -> `$array = array("Id;Imie_i_nazwisko;Nazwa_kursu;Data_kursu");
  $array = str_replace('"', '', $array);`?  Just build an array directly like `$array = array("Id", "Imie_i_nazwisko", "Nazwa_kursu", "Data_kursu")`.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing an example of the data in the database. What does a sample `var_dump($row)` look like?  You should fetch a numerically-indexed array from the DB result set, not an associative array.

Comment: array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["imie_i_nazwisko"]=> string(20) "Zenkowski ZdzisĹaw " ["nazwa_kursu"]=> string(6) "Kurs 3" ["data_kursu"]=> string(10) "2016.05.12" }

Answer (score 0):

CSV files expects "," as separator. Only MS-Excel uses ";" as separator by default.

Replace `;` for `,`, make your array with multiples elements for your header and be happy!

```
$array = array("Id;Imie_i_nazwisko;Nazwa_kursu;Data_kursu");
$array = array('Id','Imie_i_nazwisko','Nazwa_kursu','Data_kursu');
```

If you are using MS-Excel and/or need to use ";" as separator, just use this:

```
$array = array('Id','Imie_i_nazwisko','Nazwa_kursu','Data_kursu');
fputcsv($output, $array, ';');
....
fputcsv($output, $row, ';');
....
```

Comment: That's still just a one element array.  Need to quote each element.

Comment: I did as you wrote and now all table headers are in one column and rest of table rows are in one column...

Comment: CSV -> comma (,) separated values. Are you using MS-Excel to open your file?

Comment: Yes I am using MS Excel.

Comment: Take a look at the answer, you can change the delimiter to your scenario.

Comment: I used this:  fputcsv($output, $row, ';');

Comment: And headers are now ok bu rest of table NOT. Rest of rows have one column thatlok like this:  "3,"Zenkowski ZdzisĹ‚aw ","Kurs 3",2016.05.12"

Comment: Put that delimiter ";" again: `fputcsv($output, $row, ';');`

Comment: It works Thank you VERY MuCH  Felippe Duarte :) :) :)

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps you, please mark as answer to help other people.

Comment: Ok.  Felippe Duarte Maybe do you know how to correct display latin extended signs in csv file?

Comment: This is probably a encoding problem. Check if your database is ISO-8859-X or UTF8, then output it properly. read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Thanks for your help one more time :)